Access Violation Error in Multithreaded Disk Scanning with C++
I am trying to use multithreading to scan the system disk and build a Trie tree with all the file paths. However, I encountered an issue during testing.
In my main.cpp, the program runs correctly when the loop index i is 2, 4, or 6. However, when i is 8 or 10 (sometimes i = 8 works), the program crashes with an access violation error at the line if (m_tasks.empty()) return false; in the WorkStealQueue::pop function, with the message "Access violation reading location 0x00000014".
I have tried various approaches to resolve this issue but have been unsuccessful. Any help or guidance to resolve this problem?
Below is the detailed code implementation(My operating platform is Windows.):
// workstealthreadpool.h
#pragma once

#include <deque>
#include <functional>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <vector>

class WorkStealQueue
{
public:
    WorkStealQueue() = default;
    WorkStealQueue(const WorkStealQueue& rhs) = delete;
    WorkStealQueue& operator=(const WorkStealQueue& rhs) = delete;
    ~WorkStealQueue() = default;

    void push(std::function<void()> task);
    bool pop(std::function<void()>& task);
    bool steal(std::function<void()>& task);

private:
    std::deque<std::function<void()>> m_tasks;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
};

class WorkStealThreadPool
{
public:
    explicit WorkStealThreadPool(std::size_t threadNums)
        : m_stop(false) { init(threadNums); }
    ~WorkStealThreadPool();

    template<typename Callback, typename... Args>
    auto addTask(Callback&& func, Args&&... args)->std::future<typename std::result_of<Callback(Args...)>::type>;

private:
    void init(std::size_t threadNums);
    bool stealTask(std::function<void()>& task);
    void worker(size_t index);

private:
    std::vector<std::thread> m_workThreads;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<WorkStealQueue>> m_taskQueues;
    std::atomic<bool> m_stop;
    static thread_local std::size_t m_index;
};

template<typename Callback, typename... Args>
auto WorkStealThreadPool::addTask(Callback&& func, Args&&... args) -> std::future<typename std::result_of<Callback(Args...)>::type>
{
    using returnType = typename std::result_of<Callback(Args...)>::type;
    auto task = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<returnType()>>(std::bind(std::forward<Callback>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...));
    std::future<returnType> result = task->get_future();
    {
        m_taskQueues[m_index]->push([task]() { (*task)(); });
    }
    return result;
}

// workstealthreadpool.cpp
#include "workstealthreadpool.h"

void WorkStealQueue::push(std::function<void()> task)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    m_tasks.emplace_back(std::move(task));
}

bool WorkStealQueue::pop(std::function<void()>& task)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    if (m_tasks.empty()) return false;
    task = std::move(m_tasks.front());
    m_tasks.pop_front();
    return true;
}

bool WorkStealQueue::steal(std::function<void()>& task)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
    if (m_tasks.empty()) return false;
    task = std::move(m_tasks.back());
    m_tasks.pop_back();
    return true;
}

thread_local std::size_t WorkStealThreadPool::m_index;

void WorkStealThreadPool::init(std::size_t threadNums)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < threadNums; ++i)
    {
        m_taskQueues.emplace_back(std::make_unique<WorkStealQueue>());
        m_workThreads.emplace_back(&WorkStealThreadPool::worker, this, i);
    }
}

WorkStealThreadPool::~WorkStealThreadPool()
{
    m_stop = true;
    for (std::thread& workerThread : m_workThreads)
    {
        if (workerThread.joinable())
        {
            workerThread.join();
        }
    }
}

bool WorkStealThreadPool::stealTask(std::function<void()>& task)
{
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < m_taskQueues.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::size_t index = (m_index + i + 1) % m_taskQueues.size();
        if (m_taskQueues[index]->steal(task))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void WorkStealThreadPool::worker(std::size_t index)
{
    m_index = index;
    while (!m_stop)
    {
        std::function<void()> task;
        if (m_taskQueues[m_index]->pop(task) || stealTask(task))
        {
            task();
        }
        else
        {
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
    }
}

// scanner.h
#pragma once

#include "workstealthreadpool.h"
#include <QMap>
#include <QString>

struct TrieNode
{
    QMap<TrieNode*, QString> childs;
    TrieNode* parent = nullptr;
};

class Scanner
{
public:
    explicit Scanner(std::size_t threadNums);
    virtual ~Scanner();
    virtual void scanDrives(const QStringList& drives);
    virtual bool isScanCompleted();
    virtual std::vector<TrieNode*> fetchScanResults();

private:
    void scanCore(const QString& currentPath, TrieNode* parent);
    void clearTrie(TrieNode* root);

private:
    TrieNode* m_root;
    WorkStealThreadPool* m_threadPool;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::vector<TrieNode*> m_fileNodes;
    std::atomic<int> m_taskCount;
};

#ifdef _DEBUG
void Print(TrieNode* root);
void Print(std::vector<TrieNode*>* fileNodes);
#endif

// scanner.cpp
#include "scanner.h"
#include <QDir>

Scanner::Scanner(std::size_t threadNums)
    : m_root(nullptr)
    , m_threadPool(nullptr)
    , m_taskCount(0)
{
    if (threadNums != 0)
    {
        m_threadPool = new WorkStealThreadPool(threadNums);
    }
}

Scanner::~Scanner()
{
    delete m_threadPool;
    clearTrie(m_root);
}

void Scanner::scanDrives(const QStringList& drives)
{
    clearTrie(m_root);
    m_fileNodes.clear();
    m_root = new TrieNode();
    for (const QString& drive : drives)
    {
        TrieNode* child = new TrieNode();
        child->parent = m_root;
        m_root->childs[child] = drive;
        scanCore(drive, child);
    }
}

bool Scanner::isScanCompleted()
{
    return m_taskCount.load(std::memory_order_acquire) == 0;
}

std::vector<TrieNode*> Scanner::fetchScanResults()
{
    if (!isScanCompleted())
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        return m_fileNodes;
    }
    return m_fileNodes;
}

void Scanner::scanCore(const QString& currentPath, TrieNode* parent)
{
    QDir dir(currentPath);
    if (!dir.exists()) return;

    QStringList fileNames = dir.entryList(QDir::Files);
    for (const QString& fileName : fileNames)
    {
        TrieNode* child = new TrieNode();
        child->parent = parent;
        parent->childs[child] = fileName;

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        m_fileNodes.emplace_back(child);
    }

    QStringList subdirNames = dir.entryList(QDir::Dirs | QDir::NoDotAndDotDot);
    for (const QString& subdirName : subdirNames)
    {
        QString childPath = currentPath + QDir::separator() + subdirName;
        TrieNode* child = new TrieNode();
        child->parent = parent;
        parent->childs[child] = subdirName + "/";

        if (m_threadPool)
        {
            m_taskCount.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_release);
            m_threadPool->addTask([this, childPath, child]
                {
                    scanCore(childPath, child);
                    m_taskCount.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_acquire);
                }
            );
        }
        else {
            scanCore(childPath, child);
        }
    }

}

void Scanner::clearTrie(TrieNode* root)
{
    if (root == nullptr || root->childs.empty()) return;
    for (auto iter = root->childs.begin(); iter != root->childs.end(); ++iter)
    {
        clearTrie(iter.key());
    }
    delete root;
}

#ifdef _DEBUG
void Print(TrieNode* root)
{
    static int level = 0;
    if (root == nullptr || root->childs.empty()) return;
    for (auto iter = root->childs.begin(); iter != root->childs.end(); ++iter)
    {
        qDebug().noquote() << QString("    ").repeated(level) << iter.value();
        ++level;
        Print(iter.key());
        --level;
    }
}
#endif

#ifdef _DEBUG
void Print(std::vector<TrieNode*>* fileNodes)
{
    for (TrieNode* fileNode : *fileNodes)
    {
        qDebug().noquote() << fileNode->parent->childs[fileNode];
    }
}
#endif

//main.cpp
#include "scanner.h"
#include <QStorageInfo>
#include <chrono>

void TestScanDrives(Scanner& scanner, const QStringList& drives)
{
    scanner.scanDrives(drives);
    while (!scanner.isScanCompleted())
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

int main()
{
    QStringList drives;
    for (const QStorageInfo& drive : QStorageInfo::mountedVolumes())
    {
        if (drive.isValid() && drive.isReady())
        {
            drives << drive.rootPath();
        }
    }

    for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i += 2)
    {
        Scanner scanner(i);
        TestScanDrives(scanner, drives);
    }
    
    return 0;
}

I carefully reviewed the implementation of the WorkStealQueue class, particularly the pop and push methods, to ensure they handle tasks correctly. I adjusted the memory order of the atomic variable m_taskCount to different values to see if it affected the issue. I attempted to improve the thread synchronization and task termination logic in WorkStealThreadPool but did not see significant improvements.

Use your debugger to examine the call stack and the variables at the time of the crash.

Not related but this if (root == nullptr || root->childs.empty()) return; is a memory leak. It should be if (root == nullptr) return;. As it is, you are failing to delete root in the case that it has no children.

you have unsynchronized access and modification to m_taskQueues.size() and m_taskQueues[index]
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < threadNums; ++i)
    {
        m_taskQueues.emplace_back(std::make_unique<WorkStealQueue>());
        m_workThreads.emplace_back(&WorkStealThreadPool::worker, this, i);
    }

when a worker spawns, it can try to steal work from the thread after it, and m_taskQueues.size() will not be synchronized with m_taskQueues[index] (because there is no mutex on m_taskQueues, and the other thread may see size incremented but not see the vector data modified because that's a race, also it may not see the queue fully constructed because those are not atomic pointers), so split this loop into two.
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < threadNums; ++i)
    {
        m_taskQueues.emplace_back(std::make_unique<WorkStealQueue>());
    }
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < threadNums; ++i)
    {
        m_workThreads.emplace_back(&WorkStealThreadPool::worker, this, i);
    }

spawning a thread is a synchronization point, when it happens the queues will all be fully constructed, so there will be no race on m_taskQueues.size().
